# php delay when sending mails from txt list

Tags: php, phpmailer

i have this script for sending mails from a emails.txt list and is working fine but is there a way to delay the sending of emails from the list?
Any help is appreciated,thanks!

This is the Php sender script:

```
if($_POST)
{

     $recipient_email    = '';  

      $name    = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
      $from_email = filter_var($_POST["sender_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $bcc    = filter_var($_POST["bcc"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
    $reply_to_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
        $mesaj        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

        //Get uploaded file data
    $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name        = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
    $file_size        = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
    $file_type        = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
    $file_error       = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

      $lista    = $_FILES['lista']['tmp_name'];

    if($file_error > 0)
    {
        die('Upload error or No files uploaded');
    }

         $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name,'rb');

         // Now read the file content into a variable
         $content = fread($file,filesize($file_tmp_name));

         // close the file
         fclose($handle);

         // Now we need to encode it and split it into acceptable length lines
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_tmp_name)));

          $uid = md5(date('r', time()));

      //header
       $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$from_email.">\r\n";
       $headers .= "Bcc: $bcc\r\n";
       $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."\r\n";
       $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
       $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";

$message = "--PHP-mixed-$uid\r\n"."Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$uid\"\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--PHP-alt-$uid\r\n"."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

//Insert the html message.
 $message .= $mesaj;
 $message .="\r\n\r\n--PHP-alt-$uid--\r\n\r\n";

//include attachment
$message .= "--PHP-mixed-$uid\r\n"."Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"."Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";
$message .= $encoded_content;
$message .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$message .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
$message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$uid--";

    $list = fopen($lista, "r");

    if ($list) {
         while (($line = fgets($list)) !== false) {

            if (!mail($line, $subject, $message, $headers)) 
            { 
                echo "Eroare! Nu am putut trimite mailurile."; 
            }
            else
            { 

                echo "Mailurile au fost trimise!"; 
            }


            }  
fclose($list);
        }
}
```

Html form fields:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
<label>Name <input type="text" name="sender_name" /> </label> 
</br><label>Mail <input type="email" name="sender_email" /> </label> 
<label>Bcc <input type="text" name="bcc" /> </label> 
</br><label>Subject <input type="text" name="subject" /> </label> 
</br> <label>Message <textarea name="message"></textarea> </label> 
</br><label>attachment <input type="file" name="my_file" /></label>
</br><label>Mail list <input type="file" name="lista" /></label>

</br> <label><input type="submit" name="button" value="Fire :)" /></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Use the `sleep()` function to pause the script.

Comment: you can use sleep(3) for example to pause it for three seconds. then continue the loop

Comment: Any delay you add using sleep() will also delay the response time to your user. I noticed everything is wrapped with if($_POST). Is a user posting to this script from an online form? Did you want to delay sending the email to a later scheduled time?

Comment: i think he is just going through a list of emails and sending to all, in that case sleep will do what he wants, but good point.

Comment: I want each email from the txt list to be sent with a delay of 3 or 5 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the sleep() command to pause it

```
while (($line = fgets($list)) !== false) {

        if (!mail($line, $subject, $message, $headers)) 
        { 
            echo "Eroare! Nu am putut trimite mailurile."; 
        }
        else
        { 

            echo "Mailurile au fost trimise!"; 
        }

       sleep(3)
        }
```

for example